How to create csv files based on column value
I have a master dataset in pandas usa_df that looks like this
usa_df = {
    "state_name": ["Alabama", "Alabama", "Alaska", "Alaska", "Arkansas"],
    "persons": [1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
    "day_week": ["monday", "monday", "tuesday", "monday", "tuesday"]
}

There are about 200k rows in the dataset, and each state name appears for several thousand rows. Each row is a recorded crime, with the state name, persons, and day of the week being datapoints out of about a hundred).
I have a code that filters the state_name column for a specific state and then exports it as a csv
state_df = usa_df[usa_df.state_name == "Alabama"]
state_df.reset_index(drop=True)
os.chdir("/path/to/file")
state_df.to_csv("./Alabama.csv", index=False)

This method works fine, but I am trying to find a way that will automatically create a file for each state without having to do this fifty times.
Being new, I don't know how to proceed from here beyond maybe setting a list of states as  a list[str], but beyond that I'm lost. Is it possible to automatically create all 50 files for each row that matches a specific state? Thanks for your help!

Can you query the state_name field for unique values, then loop over them?

See e.g. this post.

A quick and simple solution would be using a for loop over all unique state names. You can get them from your dataframe itself:
import pandas as pd

usa_df = {
    "state_name": ["Alabama", "Alabama", "Alaska", "Alaska", "Arkansas"],
    "persons": [1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
    "day_week": ["monday", "monday", "tuesday", "monday", "tuesday"]
}

usa_df = pd.DataFrame(usa_df)

for current_name in sorted(set(usa_df.state_name)):
    state_df = usa_df[usa_df.state_name == current_name]
    state_df.to_csv(f"/path/to/file/{current_name}.csv", index=False)

The more efficient solution, as pointed out in @mozway's comment, would be using grouping, so as to not filter the dataframe multiple times:
import pandas as pd

usa_df = {
    "state_name": ["Alabama", "Alabama", "Alaska", "Alaska", "Arkansas"],
    "persons": [1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
    "day_week": ["monday", "monday", "tuesday", "monday", "tuesday"]
}

usa_df = pd.DataFrame(usa_df)

for current_name, current_group in usa_df.groupby("state_name"):
    current_group.to_csv(f"/path/to/file/{current_name}.csv", index=False)

Also note:

You don't need to reset the index, as you save with index=False anyway.
Rather than changing your current working directory, you can give the full path to the to_csv() method.


That actually wouldn't be quick/efficient. It would need to filter the file again for each value, which has a quadratic behavior. Simple: for name, g in df.groupby('col'): g.to_csv(f'{name}.csv')

@mozway I meant "quick" in the sense of "code adaptation time"

@mozway But you are right, of course. If you don't mind, I will amend my answer. Otherwise, feel free to provide your own and I will delete mine.

feel free to update your answer, but I closed the question since it's a duplicate ;)

That has worked great, thanks very much! I'll look up groups and loops etc to have a better understanding of it, thanks again to both of you!
